# how do you select column from a text file using perl

Tags: perl, addition

I want to subtract values in one column from another column and add the differences.How do I do this in perl? I am new to perl.Hence I am unable to figure out how to go about it. Kindly help me.

Comment: Are the columns fixed width or by what are the columns delimited?

Answer (score 3):

The first thing is to separate the data into columns.  In this case, the columns are separated by a space.  `split(/ /)` will return a list of the columns.

To subtract one from the other, its pulling the values out of the the list and subtracting them.

At the end, you add the difference to the running sum and then loop over the data.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

my $sum = 0;

while(<DATA>) {
    my @vals = split(/ /);
    my $diff = $vals[1] - $vals[0];
    $sum += $diff;
}

print $sum,"\n";

__DATA__
1 3
3 5
5 7
```

This will print out `6` --- (3 - 1) + (5 - 3) + (7 - 5)

Comment: Using `split / /` is almost never what you want, since it will create a field for every space, turning `foo  bar   baz` into `'foo', '', 'bar','','','baz'`. Use either the default `' '`, or the specific delimiter.

Answer (score 2):

FYI, if you combine the autosplit (`-a`), loop (`n`) and command-line program (`-e`) arguments (see [perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)), you can shorten this to a one-liner, much like `awk`:

```
perl -ane "$sum += $F[1] - $F[0]; END { print $sum }" filename
```